# identities similar to Plouffe

Tags: calculus

It posible sum the series as close form using elliptic functions
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{\pi ^2 k} k^2}{e^{2 \pi ^2 k}+1}=-\frac{i \psi _e^{(2)}\left(1+\frac{i \pi }{2}\right)}{8 \pi ^3}-\frac{i \psi _e^{(2)}\left(1-\frac{i \pi }{2}\right)}{8 \pi ^3}+\frac{1}{16 \pi ^3}$$

Comment: I was wondering how did you manage to keep such a low reputation after asking tons of questions on MSE, but I realize most of them (including this one) are badly written and with no effort at all. Here it is not even clear what you are asking: an identity is stated, an identity holds. Are you looking for a proof of it or what else?

Comment: Also, Simon Plouffe is a person, and I guess he would be grateful to have his surname mentioned with a capital letter.

Comment: asking  means to open; Open the possibility to knowledge ,reputations do not means nothing to me but this is a great media to share maths..Buonanotte Mr. Jack ...

Comment: $\psi_e^{(2)}$ is not standard. You are allowed to define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. If one knows the definition of the [$q$-gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-gamma_function),
$$
\Gamma_q(t)
=(1-q)^{1-t}\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1-q^{k}}{1-q^{k+t}},\quad |q|<1,
$$then by considering the logarithmic derivative with respect to $t$, one obtains the [$q$-digamma function $\psi_{q}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html), satisfying  the identity
$$
\psi_q(t):=\frac{\Gamma'_q(t)}{\Gamma_q(t)}=-\ln(1-q)+\ln q\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{q^{kt}}{1-q^{k+t}},\quad |q|<1,
$$ then by differentiating twice with respect to $t$, one gets
$$
\psi_q^{(2)}(t)=(\ln q)^3\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^2q^{kt}}{1-q^{k+t}},\quad |q|<1,
$$
this gives the OP identity if one observes that
$$
\frac{e^{\pi ^2 k}}{e^{2 \pi ^2\frac{}{} k}+1}=\frac{i}{2(1-e^{\pi ^2 k+i \pi/2})}-\frac{i}{2(1-e^{\pi ^2 k-i \pi/2})}.
$$